# sliding effect for horizontal menu is needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, horizontal-scrolling

I need a effect for my horizontal navigation menu like this:

http://www.piccante.co/lavalamp/demo.html

I try it but it seems it doesn't work with new version of jquery.

Would you suggest any newer version of this like of menu effect?

Thank you.

Comment: It worked for me with the latest jquery. Are you using the Easing plugin and their CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Lavalamp working with the latest jQuery. The image one won't work because I don't think I can add images to jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/DEgU8/4/

Comment: thank you. it is ok with last version of jquery. it was my falut.i replaced the wrong file. ;)